# Polymer 1.0: What properties are available in the user object using <firebase-auth>?

Tags: authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0

#### Question

> **Besides `uid`, what properties does the `user` object have available in the `<firebase-auth>` element after successful login?**

And how can I expose the entire object for viewing? `JSON.stringify(user)` returns `null`.

---

#### Documentation

- [Documentation is here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth)
- [Demo on Github](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)

---

#### Example

In the following code, `user.uid` works. But how do I see the complete `user` object (instead of just `user.uid` — see line 60)? I have tried `JSON.stringify(user)` but nothing works.

---

#### Code

[Copied from demo](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->
<link rel="import" href="../../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../firebase-auth.html">
<dom-module id="x-login">
  <template>
    <firebase-auth id="firebaseLogin" user="{{user}}" status-known="{{statusKnown}}" location="https://polymer-tests.firebaseio.com" provider="{{provider}}" on-error="errorHandler" on-user-created="userSuccessHandler" on-password-changed="userSuccessHandler" on-password-reset="userSuccessHandler" on-user-removed="userSuccessHandler"></firebase-auth>

    Firebase location:
    <input value="https://polymer-tests.firebaseio.com" size="40" disabled>
    <br>

    Provider type:
    <select value="{{provider::change}}">
      <option>anonymous</option>
      <option>facebook</option>
      <option>github</option>
      <option>google</option>
      <option>twitter</option>
      <option>password</option>
    </select>
    <em>Only 'anonymous', 'google', and 'password' are activated for demo Firebase account</em>
    <br>

    Login params (JSON):
    <input value="{{params::input}}" id="params">
    <em>Required by some provider types</em>
    <br>

    <div hidden$="{{computePasswordHidden(provider)}}">
      <br><em>Password-specific options:</em><br>
      <input placeholder="email" value="{{email::input}}">
      <input placeholder="password" value="{{password::input}}">
      <button on-tap="createUserHandler" disabled$="{{computeCreateUserDisabled(email, password)}}">Create user</button>
      <br>
      <input placeholder="new password" value="{{newPassword::input}}">
      <button on-tap="changePasswordHandler" disabled$="{{computeChangePasswordDisabled(email, password, newPassword)}}">Change password</button>
      <br>
      <button on-tap="resetPasswordHandler" disabled$="{{computeResetPasswordDisabled(email, password)}}">Reset password</button>
      <button on-tap="removeUserHandler" disabled$="{{computeRemoveUserDisabled(email, password)}}">Remove user</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="message">[[message]]</div>
    <br>

    <button on-tap="login" hidden$="{{computeLoginHidden(statusKnown, user)}}">Login</button>
    <button on-tap="logout" hidden$="{{computeLogoutHidden(statusKnown, user)}}">Logout</button>

    <h3>Login status:</h3>
    <p>{{computeLoginStatus(statusKnown, user)}}</p>

    <h3>User ID:</h3>
    <pre>{{user.uid}}</pre>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-login',

    properties: {
      provider: {
        type: String,
        value: 'anonymous'
      },

      message: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      },

      email: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      },

      password: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      },

      user: {
        type: Object,
        value: null
      },

      statusKnown: {
        type: Boolean
      }
    },

    login: function() {
      var params;

      try {
        params = JSON.parse(this.params);
      } catch (e) {
        params = null;
      }

      if (this.provider == 'password') {
        params = params || {};
        params.email = this.email;
        params.password = this.password;
      }

      this.$.firebaseLogin.login(params);
    },

    logout: function() {
      this.$.firebaseLogin.logout();
    },

    errorHandler: function(e) {
      this.message = 'Error: ' + e.detail.message;
    },

    userSuccessHandler: function(e) {
      this.message = e.type + ' success!';
    },

    createUserHandler: function(e) {
      this.$.firebaseLogin.createUser(this.email, this.password);
    },

    changePasswordHandler: function(e) {
      this.$.firebaseLogin.changePassword(this.email, this.password, this.newPassword);
    },

    resetPasswordHandler: function(e) {
      this.$.firebaseLogin.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email);
    },

    computePasswordHidden: function(provider) {
      return provider !== 'password';
    },

    computeCreateUserDisabled: function(email, password) {
      return !email || !password;
    },

    computeChangePasswordDisabled: function(email, password, newPassword) {
      return !email || !password || !newPassword;
    },

    computeResetPasswordDisabled: function(email, password) {
      return !email || !password;
    },

    computeRemoveUserDisabled: function(email, password) {
      return !email || !password;
    },

    computeLoginHidden: function(statusKnown, user) {
      return !statusKnown || !!user;
    },

    computeLogoutHidden: function(statusKnown, user) {
      return !statusKnown || !user;
    },

    computeLoginStatus: function(statusKnown, user) {
      if (statusKnown && user) {
        return 'Logged in';
      }

      if (statusKnown) {
        return 'Logged out';
      }

      return 'Unknown (checking status...)';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the provider.

---

#### Google

- [Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html#section-logging-in)
- `authData` object: `user` (root)

{

```
  uid: "string",
  provider: "string",
  token: "string",
  auth: {},
  expires: "number",
  google: {
    id: "string",
    accessToken: "string",
    displayName: "string",
    email: "string",
    profileImageURL: "string",
    cachedUserProfile: "string",
  }
}
```

---

#### Facebook

- [Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html#section-logging-in)

---

#### Twitter

- [Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/twitter.html#section-logging-in)

---

#### Github

- [Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/github.html#section-logging-in)